# Check if in one integer array are exactly a number of matches in c#?

Tags: arrays, c#-4.0

I have an array of 25 numbers and i have another array of 15 numbers.
What is the fastest way to found exactly (no more, no less) 5 matches of the 15 numbers in the 25 numbers array?

Example:

```
int[] array1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25 }

int[] array2 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 36, 77, 88, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55 }

int[] array3 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 26, 17, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34 }

int[] array4 = { 1, 2, 3, 28, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40 }
```

in the example the array2 is the valid array because it has exactly 5 matches but the array3 and array4 are not valid.

Comment: Are all of your arrays always guaranteed to be sorted? Should the method return whether there are exactly 5 matches between two arrays, or should it return the matches if there are exactly 5?

Comment: Also, have you actually _tried_ anything on your own? Include some code to show that you've put effort into solving your own problem.

Comment: Are all the numbers distinct in all arrays? If so, LINQ should make this pretty trivial.

Comment: do you want to find out the common element in  array1 and array2.

Comment: The first question you make it's no.. the array may not be sorted.
The problem is based on a game... the array1 is the world of numbers and the array2, array3 and array4 are the 3 players each with 15 numbers in his play.. so the only player that will win is the one that has exactly 5 matches of the array1. So i need to know how many players have exactly 5 matches to know what players i have to set the prize.

Comment: Have you made any effort? Without your own code, it just sounds like you want someone else to do the work for you.

Comment: Yes i made an effort.. what question is that? if it is easy for you then do not criticize others for not knowing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int[] array1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25 };
int[] array2 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 36, 77, 88, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55 };

int numMatches = array1.Intersect(array2).Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] array1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25 };

int[] array2 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 36, 77, 88, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55 };

int[] array3 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 26, 17, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34 };

int[] array4 = { 1, 2, 3, 28, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40 };

var matches = 
     from set1 in array1 
     join set2 in array2 on set1 equals set2
     select set1;
 if (matches.Count() == 5)
        return true;
 else
       return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

This method does not do too much work:

```
bool CompareCount(int[] array1, int[] array2, int count)
{
    // Check that the arrays contain at least count of integers.
    if (array1 == null || array1.length < count) return false;
    if (array2 == null || array2.length < count) return false;

    // Check that the first count integers are identical.
    for(int i = 0; i < count; count++)
       if (array1[i] <> array2[i]) return false;
    // If one of the arrays only contains count integers, then its okay.
    if (array1.length == count || array2.length == count) return true;

    // If the next integers are different, then its okay. 
    return array1[count] != array2[count];
}
```